# MVC Partial View Model has empty properties on GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a piece of insanity I'm trying to resolve.  For 1 single partial view in my project I have the following issue.  The view that leads to this view has the same model, and works correctly

Assume that ModelProperty1 = "HERE"

```
@Model.Property1                        outputs nothing
@("M" + Model.Property1 + "M")          outputs "MM"
@Html.Display(Model.Property1)          outputs nothing
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property1)      outputs nothing
@string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Property1) returns true
@Html.TextBox("TEST", Model.Property1)  outputs an input element with no value
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1)      outputs an input element with the value of "HERE"
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property1)       outputs an input element with the value of "HERE"
```

Now, if it wasn't for the last couple, I'd assume I'd done something stupid.
Coupled with this is that "Model" is not available in IntelliSense or Quick Watch while debugging the view.

I'm wondering if some pipeline item somewhere has gotten screwed up.  If anyone has any advice, I'm desperate to try it.

Comment: can you show your controller?

Comment: I could, but after 2 days it's spontaneously started working again about 5 minutes ago while I was working on another view.

Answer (score 0):

In your PartialView:

Since you know it has the same model as the Parent View, try defining the model.
@model YourModelClass

In your ParentView:

Try passing the Model to the partialView explicitly `@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", Model)`

Is Property1 the only property that has this strange behavior? What is the Type of Property1?

Comment: @model was defined.  It's not a parent/child view, it was a list => detail transfer  Property1 was a string (I noticed on the shipping container #), but problem was happening with other string properties (harder to tell with structs) and was not happening with strings in a child view